# Oracle sequence is not generating

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a table Person contains fields are personName,personId and without specifying the primary I added some values at the table. The values in the table Person are

```
 ('muni',1)   
 ('Ganesh',1)
```

I need to add primary key as personId and modify the column as autogenerated. So, I tried to generate the sequence by the following query for generating trigger as

```
declare           
id  number;     
begin  
select max(rownum)+1 into id from Person;  
execute immediate 'create sequence personseq start with '||to_char(id);  
end;
```

If i execute the above query when the values are in the table, then it execute correctly, But when I have the empty table that means there is no entry in the table, then the above query is not generating the sequence.

I tried by if statement also.

```
declare  
id  number;  
begin  
select max(rownum)+1 into id from Person;  
if (id=null) then  
execute immediate 'create sequence personseq start with '||to_char(1);  
else  
execute immediate 'create sequence personseq start with '||to_char(id);  
end if;  
end;
```

The system says the error no is `ORA01722`, which denotes the number I give Invalid number. But I don't know where is the mistake?
Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select nvl(max(rownum),0)+1 into id from Person;
```

When table is empty max(rownum) will return null and when you add null to a value will always return null, so you need to convert any nulls to 0 so that 0 + 1 will return 1 and not null

Comment: I already read that concept in my school day but I really forget about nvl. Thanks for remind that.

Comment: But I compared the id as null and not any valid numbers

Comment: @muniganesh, as be here now mentioned, you should always check for null using IS NULL, null is not equal to null, null is something that is not defined so you cannot compare them.

Answer (score 1):

upd: just noticed more important flaw than count/rownum.

`id=null`. Never do that, this doesn't work.

You check whether a value is null this way: `id is null`.

[NULLS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm)

Use `count(*)`.

```
12:03:55 SYSTEM@saz-dev> create table person as
12:04:05   2  select 'muni' name, 1 attribute from dual union all
12:04:32   3  select 'ganesh' name, 1 attribute from dual;

Table created.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.07
12:04:47 SYSTEM@saz-dev> ed
Wrote file S:\tools\buffer.sql

  1  declare
  2  id  number;
  3  begin
  4  select count(*)+1 into id from person;
  5  execute immediate 'create sequence personseq start with '||to_char(id)||' increment by 1';
  6* end;
12:05:52   7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.06
12:05:53 SYSTEM@saz-dev> select object_name from user_objects where object_name = 'PERSONSEQ';

OBJECT_NAME
---------------------------------------
PERSONSEQ

Elapsed: 00:00:00.08
12:06:16 SYSTEM@saz-dev> truncate table person;

Table truncated.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.32
12:06:27 SYSTEM@saz-dev> drop sequence personseq;

Sequence dropped.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.20
12:06:33 SYSTEM@saz-dev>  declare
12:06:38   2   id  number;
12:06:38   3   begin
12:06:38   4   select count(*)+1 into id from person;
12:06:38   5   execute immediate 'create sequence personseq start with '||to_char(id)||' increment by 1';
12:06:38   6   end;
12:06:39   7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.03
12:06:40 SYSTEM@saz-dev> select personseq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1

Elapsed: 00:00:00.04
```

Answer (score 0):

create a sequence once like this

```
CREATE SEQUENCE person_seq
 START WITH     1000
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;
```

than use - 'person_seq.nextval' for each insertion of new record
e.g.

insert into person (name,id) values('abc',person_seq.nextval)

Comment: I agree, this is far more reliable and efficient than select the max from the table